# How can I stop a Lua coroutine from outside the function?

Tags: lua, coroutine

I'm trying to create a dispatcher which schedules multiple coroutines. The dispatcher needs to pause the coroutine, I can't figure out how to do this.

**Update**
Instead of kill, I meant to pause the coroutine from the outside.

Comment: Coroutine is a garbage-collectable object.  Just remove all references to it.

Comment: What effect do you expect from killing a coroutine? Isn't it enough to remove it from the dispatch queue?

Answer (score 1):

You can kill a coroutine by setting a debug hook on it that calls `error()` from that hook. The next time the hook is called, it will trigger `error()` call, which will abort the coroutine:

```
local co = coroutine.create(function()
  while true do print(coroutine.yield()) end
end)
coroutine.resume(co, 1)
coroutine.resume(co, 2)
debug.sethook(co, function()error("almost dead")end, "l")
print(coroutine.resume(co, 3))
print(coroutine.status(co))
```

This prints:

```
2
3
false   coro-kill.lua:6: almost dead
dead
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't know that. Is there a way to pause the coroutine instead of killing it?

Comment: Not though the debug hook; pausing it would require calling `yield`, but calling `yield` from the debug hook yields `attempt to yield across a C-call boundary` error.

Answer (score 1):

library that will yield when you return true in the hook that been set with `debug.sethook(co, function() return true end, "y")`

the library is enough to create multitask lua system just run `require("yieldhook")` at very first of your code further info at the git

https://github.com/evg-zhabotinsky/yieldhook

Answer (score -1):

use coroutine.yield(coroutine-you-want-to-pause)